# Difference of two maps in groovy using collectEntries

Tags: groovy

I am trying to find the difference between values in two maps

```
@Test
void testCollecEntries() {
    def mapOne= ["A":900,"B":2000,"C":1500]
    def maptwo = ["A":1000,"D":1500,"B":1500]

    def balanceMap = maptwo.collectEntries { key, value-> [key:value-mapOne[key]]   }

    println balanceMap
}
```

I am trying to find the difference of values from maptwo with that of the values from mapOne. If the entry doesn't exist i need to ignore. This gives me a null pointer exception.

Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It will throw NPE because you are looking for key "D" in mapOne which is not available.
You can avoid that by a null safe operation and default value to 0.

```
def one= [A:900, B:2000, C:1500]
def two = [A:1000, D:1500, B:1500]

def result = two.collectEntries{k,v -> [k, (v - (one[k]?:0))]}
println result

//Print
[A:100, D:1500, B:-500]
```

In case, you want to consider the common keys then use:

```
def result = two.collectEntries{k,v -> one[k] ? [k, (v - one[k])] : [:]}

//or
//def result = two.collectEntries{k,v -> (k in one.keySet()) ? [k, (v - one[k])] : [:]}

//Print
[A:100, B:-500]
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried that one earlier but somehow I missed the braces.

Comment: Any hint how can I consider only if key is in both the maps ?

Comment: @KiranChitturi See my update. You can do that by proactively checking whether the key-value pair exists in the first map.

Answer (score 0):

You could look at this good example: http://groovyconsole.appspot.com/script/364002